# How i can resolve this i try so many things but i failed to solve?

Tags: image, azure-machine-learning-service

```
    import torch
    from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline,             StableDiffusionImg2ImgPipeline,StableDiffusionInpaintPipelineLegacy, DDIMScheduler, AutoencoderKL
    from PIL import Image
    from ip_adapter import IPAdapter
```

When i run above lines of code i got error as mention below:

```
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
    File ~/IP-Adapter/imgToimg_venv/lib/python3.8/site-  packages/diffusers/utils/import_utils.py:710, in _LazyModule._get_module(self, module_name)
        709 try:
    --> 710     return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
        711 except Exception as e:

    File /usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py:127, in import_module(name, package)
        126         level += 1
    --> 127 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

    File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1014, in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

    File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:991, in _find_and_load(name, import_)

    File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:973, in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'diffusers.models.autoencoder_kl'
 
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
    Cell In[33], line 2
          1 import torch
    ----> 2 from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline, StableDiffusionImg2ImgPipeline,      StableDiffusionInpaintPipelineLegacy, DDIMScheduler, AutoencoderKL
          3 from PIL import Image
          5 from ip_adapter import IPAdapter

     File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1039, in _handle_fromlist(module, fromlist, import_,  recursive)

     File ~/IP-Adapter/imgToimg_venv/lib/python3.8/site-     packages/diffusers/utils/import_utils.py:701, in _LazyModule.__getattr__(self, name)
        699 elif name in self._class_to_module.keys():
        700     module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
     --> 701     value = getattr(module, name)
        702 else:
        703     raise AttributeError(f"module {self.__name__} has no attribute {name}")

    File ~/IP-Adapter/imgToimg_venv/lib/python3.8/site-     packages/diffusers/utils/import_utils.py:700, in _LazyModule.__getattr__(self, name)
        698     value = self._get_module(name)
        699 elif name in self._class_to_module.keys():
    --> 700     module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
        701     value = getattr(module, name)
        702 else:

    File ~/IP-Adapter/imgToimg_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/diffusers/utils/import_utils.py:712, in _LazyModule._get_module(self, module_name)
        710     return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
        711 except Exception as e:
    --> 712     raise RuntimeError(
        713         f"Failed to import {self.__name__}.{module_name} because of the following error     (look up to see its"
        714         f" traceback):\n{e}"
        715     ) from e

    RuntimeError: Failed to import diffusers.models.autoencoder_kl because of the following error      (look up to see its traceback):
    No module named 'diffusers.models.autoencoder_kl'
```

i tried to upgrade the diffusers but still i got these problem. this is a part of image generation git repo you can just search "IP-adpater" actually i am working on image generation task previously i am done my work on my local system and now first time i am working in server where i got GPU access but same code run successful when i shifted to server i got these error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the improper setup of the environment for `IP-adapter`.
Follow below steps for correct installation.

After starting your compute instance, create a setup bash script for `IP-adapter`.

[image]

You will get the prompt below. Select **File type** as `Bash` and give the file a name.

[image]

After creating, add the content below to the file and save.

```
# install latest diffusers
pip install diffusers==0.22.1 transformers

# install ip-adapter
pip install git+https://github.com/tencent-ailab/IP-Adapter.git

curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install git-lfs

# download the models
cd IP-Adapter
git lfs install
git clone https://huggingface.co/h94/IP-Adapter
mv IP-Adapter/models models
mv IP-Adapter/sdxl_models sdxl_models
```

[image]

Next, open the terminal of your compute instance and select the `Azureml PyTorch and Tensorflow` environment using the command below. You will need to select the same kernel while running the notebook as well.

[image]

and
`conda activate azureml_py38_PT_TF`

[image]

Next, run the script you created.

[image]

Wait for the script execution. Since it has to download large model files, it will take some time.

[image]

After execution, run your import statements in the notebook. Make sure you select the **Python 3.8 - Pytorch And Tensorflow** kernel.